# How to make Json result using JPA inheritance (spring boot)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa, inheritance

### I have an error about "findAll" when I use JPA inheritage tables.

I what make the Json result like this ["asdf" : "adf", "asdf" : "asdf"]

but the return values are like [com.example.model.AccountEntity@57af674a]

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMyInfoall", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getMemberall(@RequestBody JSONObject sendInfo) throws IOException {

        List user = UserService.findAll();
        
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        result.put("data", user);

        return result.toJSONString();
    }
```

### Service

```
public List findAll() {
    List users = UserRepository.findAll();
    return users;
}
```

### Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
}
```

### Entity

````
@Entity(name = "Users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int userkey;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String email;
}

@Entity(name = "Account")
public class AccountEntity extends UserEntity{

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String accountno;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String accountname;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int accountpw;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long balance;
}```
````

Comment: What is this "asdf" : "adf", "asdf" : "asdf"? Is it username from user table?

Comment: `[com.example.model.AccountEntity@57af674a]` seems like a `List` containing a single `AccountEntity` object. Since that class extends `UserEntity` it could be the result of your found list formatted as string, i.e. `user.toString()`

Comment: Can you clarify what your JSONObject refers to? The Java JsonObject class? Or a class you created? Seems to me returning your UserEntity object would be easier, as you're already telling Spring to return it as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to use Spring's default [`HTTPMessageConverter`s](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest), e.g. [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) for JSON.

#### Building a JSON-array from a List

But you can also use JSON.org's light-weight library like guided on [JSON-java README](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java):

1. convert the `List` to an array, e.g. `UserEntity[]`
2. create a `JSONArray` from this Java array
3. return this JSON-array *representation* formatted as String, using method `toString()`

```java
List<UserEntity> userList = // a list returned from your database/repo
UserEntity[] myArr = userList.toArray(new UserEntity[userList.size()]); // (1) convert this to an array
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(myArr);  // (2) follow the guide on JSON
return json.toString();  // (3) return the JSON-array as string
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your `UserEntity` objects to a `UserDto` DTO that would then be returned in your Controller. Rely on [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) instead of `JSONObject` managed and created by you.

```java
public class UserDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

You Service should do the mapping:

```java
public List<UserDto> findAll() {
    List<UserEntity> users = UserRepository.findAll();
    return users.stream().map(user -> // your mapping logic to UserDto object);
}
```

And your Controller just needs to return it:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMyInfoall", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<UserDto> getMemberall(@RequestBody JSONObject sendInfo) throws IOException {
    return UserService.findAll();
}
```

You can do a similar thing with `JSONObject sendInfo` and replace it with an object of your own.